# How to calculate combinations of multiple variables which can assume multiple values

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 3 variables (A,B,C); each variable can assume 3 different values (1,2,3) .
I want to calculate ho many combinations there are which follow this rule:

let's fix **A1**, then cycle on all the others variables which can assume 3 values each; then let's move on to **A2** and calculate again all the combinations by cycling over the 2 remaining variables (which can assume 3 values each); same thing for **A3**. Once I am done with A I repeat the same process with B and so on. The constrain is that the combinations must repeat only once over all:
in fact if I fix **A1** and the combination I get is (**A1** B3 C2 ), then when I fix for example **B3** I must not count (A1 **B**3 C2) because it has been already found before.

So what I need is the mathematical formula that allows me to do this calculation with a generic number of variables which can assume a generic number of values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For clarification, I am assuming we are keeping it as an *ordered pair* (A,B,C) for whatever ABC happens to be.  (I.e. we are never concerned about a permutation of the letters such as (B,A,C))

You have 3 choices for the result of A, three choices for the result of B, and 3 choices for the result of C.  By multiplication principle it is then $3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 3^3=27$.

In general, if you have $r$ variables, each of which can take $n$ values, (I.e. we have letters $(A_1, A_2,\dots, A_r)$ each of which can be any number from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, there will be $n\cdot n\cdots n = n^r$ total possibilities.

Even more generally, if you have $r$ variables, the $i^{th}$ of which can take on $n_i$ values, you will have $\prod\limits_{i=1}^r n_i$ number of possibilities.

For a simple example, you go to an icecream shop and would like to get a sundae.  A sundae consists of one flavor of icecream and any combination of toppings you'd like (some, all, or none).  If there are five flavors of icecream and four available toppings, how many *different* ice cream sundaes are possible?  Break it up via multiplication principle to first ask the question how many flavors of icecream there are (flavor 1, flavor 2,...).  Then to ask the question if you use the first topping (yes or no), yes or no to the second topping, yes or no to the third...

This is exactly the same problem as how many possibilities exist for (A,B,C,D,E) if $A\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and each of B through E are either 1 or 2.  If for example, B is 1, then don't use that topping.

There are then $5\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2=80$ possible sundaes.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your answer is super helpfull!!!

Comment: To add a bit more complexity to this answer (hopefully not too far away from  when the question was asked), but how does this change if, say variable A can be a floating-point number?

Comment: @espais it doesn't change at all.  All that matters are the number of options for each.  If some of those options are irrational numbers, or even not numbers at all, it doesn't matter

Comment: Regarding  your  first sentence in the answer, isn't it called a *tuple*, not an *ordered pair*

Comment: @Hexatonic not that it much matters, but if I were to rewrite it today I would have used the phrase "ordered *triple*".  In naming things, 2 - ordered pair, 3 - ordered tri**ple**, 4 - ordered quadr**uple**, 5 - ordered quin**tuple**, and so on... For size $n$ that would be an ordered $n$-tuple.  These triples, quadruples, and so on are collectively referred to as tuples, the word tuple by itself does not imply the size.  So, yes... *tuple* would have been a correct word to use.  So is ordered triple.  Yes, I had made a typo at the time in using *pair* instead of *triple*

Comment: @JMoravitz  sorry if I came across as a hair splitting nit picking troll. :)   I actually wanted to assure myself, as the word is so common in Python, where 1 of 4 elementary data types is called a tuple.